# Query should be changed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

I have one query this query display will be based on the day which day the hours is there based on the week it will  display.

In this hours table my start date and end date starts from 2014-01-06 2014-01-12 one week..

for eg:

```
declare @Hours as Table ( EmpId Int, Monday Time, Tuesday Time, Wednesday Time,
  Thursday Time, Friday Time, Saturday Time, Sunday Time, StartDate Date, EndDate Date );
insert into @Hours
  ( EmpId, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, StartDate, EndDate )
  values
  ( 1, '08:00', '00:00', '00:00', '00:00', '00:00', '00:00', '00:00', '2014-01-06 00:00:00.000', '2014-01-12 00:00:00.000' );
select * from @Hours;


with Week as (
  -- Build a table of all of the dates in the work week.
  select StartDate as WorkDate, EndDate
    from @Hours
  union all
  select DateAdd( day, 1, WorkDate ), EndDate
    from Week
    where WorkDate < EndDate ),
  DaysHours as (
  -- Build a table of the hours assigned to each date.
  select EmpId,
    case DatePart( weekday, W.WorkDate )
      when 1 then H.Monday
      when 2 then H.Tuesday
      when 3 then H.Wednesday
      when 4 then H.Thursday
      when 5 then H.Friday
      when 6 then H.Saturday
      when 7 then H.Sunday
      end as Hours,
    WorkDate as StartDate, WorkDate as EndDate
    from Week as W inner join
      @Hours as H on H.StartDate <= W.WorkDate and W.WorkDate <= H.EndDate )
  -- Output the non-zero hours.
  select EmpId, Hours,StartDate as StartDate, EndDate
    from DaysHours
    where Hours <> Cast( '00:00' as Time );
```

need the output like this:

```
EmpId       Hours            StartDate  EndDate
----------- ---------------- ---------- ----------
1           08:00:00.0000000 2014-01-06 2014-01-06
```

because monday only we have the value.but my output like this

```
EmpId       Hours            StartDate  EndDate
----------- ---------------- ---------- ----------
1           08:00:00.0000000 2014-01-12 2014-01-12
```

it should work based on which day the value is there.

Can any body alter in this query itself.

Thanks,

Comment: this doesn't look like mysql. Are you trying to convert your existing sql into mysql?

Comment: sorry it is sql only i will change the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After execution got

```
EmpId   Hours               StartDate   EndDate
1       08:00:00.0000000    2014-01-06  2014-01-06
```

MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: select EmpId, Hours,StartDate as StartDate, EndDate
    from DaysHours
    where Hours <> Cast( '00:00' as Time ); check this result you will not get 2014-01-06 2014-01-06

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT  x.EmpId, ca.Hours, ca.CurrentDate AS StartDate, ca.CurrentDate AS EndDate
FROM    @Hours x
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT  y.Hours, DATEADD(DAY, y.NumOfDays, x.StartDate)
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT x.Monday, 0
        UNION ALL SELECT x.Tuesday, 1
        UNION ALL SELECT x.Wednesday, 2
        UNION ALL SELECT x.Thursday, 3
        UNION ALL SELECT x.Friday, 4
        UNION ALL SELECT x.Saturday, 5
        UNION ALL SELECT x.Sunday, 6
    ) y (Hours, NumOfDays)
    WHERE y.Hours <> '00:00:00.0000000'
) ca (Hours, CurrentDate);
```